# add new Tag in XML after existing Tag in batch

Tags: xml, batch-processing

for example:

```
<a>   
   <b>valA</b>
   <b>valB</b>
</a> 
<c>
   <b>valA</b>
   <b>valB</b>
</c>
```

i would like to add a new Tag after  so the file looks like

```
<a>
   <b>valA</b>
   <b>valB</b>
</a> 
<b>
   <b>valA</b>
   <b>valB</b>
</b> 
<c>
   <b>valA</b>
   <b>valB</b>
</c>
```

can i do it in cmd batch?

Thanks

Comment: There's a ton of ways to do this but you'll probably want to use an XSLT stylesheet. Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661650/modify-xml-file-in-batch

Comment: Can you describe more what you are trying to do. Your example is not sufficient to understand what you need.

Comment: what i want to do it to add tag after specific tag that may not be the last one on my XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET source=original.xml
SET dest=result.xml
SET insert=insert.xml
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (%source%) DO (
 ECHO(%%i
 ECHO("%%i"|FIND /i "<%~1>" >nul 
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 TYPE %insert%
)
)>%dest%
GOTO :EOF
```

This should work - run `thisbatch /a` to insert the contents of the file nominated as `%insert%` after the tag specified as the first parameter.